# Common encryption "tools" between Outlook and Thunderbird

Tags: email, encryption

My company is using Thunderbird and I'm planning the deployment of mail encryption with our contacts. I'm currently assessing encryption and am getting familiar with Enigmail.

Since our customers will mostly be using Outlook, I'm wondering if there are encryption tools for Outlook compatible with (what I'd call) Enigmail encryption protocol. In short: is it possible to exchange encrypted mails between users with Thunderbird/Enigmail and Outlook/?

I'd rather to avoid:

- switching to proprietary tools, i.e. dropping Thunderbird,
- forcing our contacts to switch to Thunderbird.

Subsidiary question: what about those who use Office365?

Comment: @Murphy That is indeed my question.

Comment: Given the requirement to understand a Windows/Outlook environment, I would suggest a sister site such as Super User or Server Fault (check their on-topic scopes).

Comment: From my investigations, [PGP4win](https://www.gpg4win.org/system-requirements.html) might do. I need to do some testing. Plus getting my hands on Outlook installations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to use OpenPGP in your company for encrypting and maybe signing emails, since you're going with `Enigmail`.

Microsoft doesn't offer a native support for PGP, so you will have to use a 3rd party implementation (I've worked with `Kleopatra – Gpg4Win`).

You also need to understand that since it's not native, it will not look that good as it does in Thunderbird, but it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Look doesn't matter in the end, functionality and portability do, much more. We'll try to make our contacts understand as it's only for a couple of specific occasions that we'll use encryption.